# apply a function from different list in R using sweep function

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I have two list and each list have multiple elements, and each element is a data frame. As an example

```
set.seed(1234)
k = data.frame(a=rnorm(5,10),b=rnorm(5,10))
l = data.frame(a=rnorm(5,3),b=rnorm(5,3))

lista <- list(k=k,l=l)

k = data.frame(x=rnorm(5,20))
l = data.frame(x=rnorm(5,6))

listb <- list(k=k,l=l)



> lista
$k
          a         b
1  8.792934 10.506056
2 10.277429  9.425260
3 11.084441  9.453368
4  7.654302  9.435548
5 10.429125  9.109962

$l
         a        b
1 2.522807 2.889715
2 2.001614 2.488990
3 2.223746 2.088805
4 3.064459 2.162828
5 3.959494 5.415835


> listb
$k
         x
1 20.13409
2 19.50931
3 19.55945
4 20.45959
5 19.30628

$l
         x
1 4.551795
2 6.574756
3 4.976344
4 5.984862
5 5.064051
```

I would like to take each column from lista and a **corresponding column** in listb and apply the following formula:

```
(lista$k[1]-listb$k[1])/(abs(lista$k[1])+abs(listb$k[1]))
(lista$k[2]-listb$k[1])/(abs(lista$k[2])+abs(listb$k[1]))
```

repeat the same for `"l"`.

I tried using sweep function and Map in R as follows:

```
form <- Map(function(x,y) abs(sweep(x,1,y,FUN="-"))/(sweep(abs(x),1,abs(y),FUN="+")),lista,listb)
```

I get the following error, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)),  : 
  list of length 10 not meaningful
```

**EDIT**: Converting data.frame into matrix is able to provide desired output.

```
form <- Map(function(x,y) abs(sweep(as.matrix(x),1,as.matrix(y),FUN="-"))/(sweep(abs(as.matrix(x)),1,abs(a‌​s.matrix(y)),FUN="+")),lista,listb)
```

Comment: I wonder if something like that will work for you `listb <- Map(cbind, listb, listb) ; Map(function(x, y) (x - y) / (abs(x) + abs(y)), lista, listb)`

Comment: Thanks David. Changing dataframe into matrix in the sweep function was able to provide the desired output.

    `form <- Map(function(x,y) abs(sweep(as.matrix(x),1,as.matrix(y),FUN="-"))/(sweep(abs(as.matrix(x)),1,abs(as.matrix(y)),FUN="+")),lista,listb)`

Comment: You probably should post this as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing dataframe into matrix in the sweep function was able to provide the desired output.

```
form <- Map(function(x,y) abs(sweep(as.matrix(x),1,as.matrix(y),FUN="-"))/(sweep(abs(as.matrix(x)),1,abs(a‌​s.matrix(y)),FUN="+")),lista,listb)
```